# CentOS 7 grub option is missing after upgrading windows 8 to 10

Tags: linux, centos, windows, grub2, mbr

My system was dual booted with `CentOS 7` and `Windows 8`. 
After I reinstalled the latest `Windows 10 Pro` and removed `windows 8`, my system is only booting with `Windows 10` as the `Grub2` is not appearing at the boot time.

I assume `Grub2` is over written by `Windows MBR`. I might need to reinstall grub on my system. I don't have any clue on how to attempt this `Grub2` installation as `CentOS 7` is the latest version which is having many changes

Comment: I think you have to move from an universal grub to UEFI, as Win10 always installs itself in the mbr: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5707fd81-1e2b-407c-9597-39914802b1e4/how-can-i-keep-windows-7-64bit-from-interfering-with-the-uefi-sequence-upon-every-restart?forum=w7itproinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple with the below steps.

Booted my system with `CentOS 7` disk into a rescue mode.
Now mount my root partition by running the `chroot` command as follows.

`chroot /mnt/sysimage`

Then I installed `MBR` with the below command.

`grub-install /dev/sda`

after installing the grub boot loader I rebooted the system, and it was up with any changes to the system.

Comment: Why didn't you enter your system's "*Boot Menu*" during POST? Usually this is done by pressing some key (e.g. F12, Delete, F7, etc.) right after you power on the system.  If your system is using UEFI, which I'm assuming is the case if you're using Win10, then the BootMenu will display a list of available boot options.

Comment: As mentioned, I am unable to get the boot menu because I have reinstalled `Windows 10` over `CentOS 7`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you have MBR instead of GPT disks, since you're using Win10.

Comment: I haven't enabled the GPT, I was having lot of data, so couldn't take risk.